# ActiveX Word control - NextDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, activex

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 page with implemented Word ActiveX control (version 1.3.7) to open some documents (*.doc).

When I run the application locally, open a few documents and use the method `NextDocument` a document changed to another (everything works well) , but on another machine (same system, Word and control version) when I call the method `NextDocument` another document was opened in new Word instance. Why? I was looking for a Word setting but haven't found anything interesting.

Comment: Can you explain and add more detail on the components you are using? "Word ActiveX control" seems to be some third-party component?

Comment: About the "Word ActiveX control": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195739.aspx

Comment: I'm confused how that article refers to your problem. The article decribes how to embed ActiveX controls into Word documents. Is is that what you are doing? Please create a minimal sample so that we are able to reproduce, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve